# MySQL Syntax error on Insert Query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a non-descriptive syntax error on a MYSQL query from PHP. If I "echo" the text of the query and paste it into a MySQL query window, the code works. Here is the SQL for the query, the error code, and the error message...

```sql
INSERT INTO ADVERTISEMENTS (`user_id`, `ad_name`, `click_url`, `img_url`, `bg_color`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `timer_delay`, `add_date`) VALUES (2, 'Test New Ad', 'http://www.google.com', 'red_arrow.png', '#000000', '1980-05-11 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 5, '2013-07-14 22:21:59');
```

> Error Code: 1064
>   Error Msg: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Here is the PHP code I am using...

```
$link = mysqli_connect($UM_Settings["database_options"]["server_name"], $UM_Settings["database_options"]["username"], $UM_Settings["database_options"]["password"], $UM_Settings["database_options"]["database_name"]);

$advertisementNameNew = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['advertisementNameNew']);
$destinationURLNew = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['destinationURLNew']);
$dropboxUploadFile = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['dropboxUploadFile']);
$backgroundColorNew = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['backgroundColorNew']);
$bannerStartDateNew = DateStringToMySQL($_POST['bannerStartDateNew']);
$bannerEndDateNew = DateStringToMySQL($_POST['bannerEndDateNew']);
$bannerSetTimerNew = intval($_POST['bannerSetTimerNew']);
$tmpUserID = UM_GetCookie("UM_UserID");
$tmpAddDate = DateStringToMySQL('now');

echo "INSERT INTO ADVERTISEMENTS(`user_id`, `ad_name`, `click_url`, `img_url`, `bg_color`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `timer_delay`, `add_date`) VALUES ($tmpUserID, '$advertisementNameNew', '$destinationURLNew', '$dropboxUploadFile', '$backgroundColorNew', '$bannerStartDateNew', '$bannerEndDateNew', $bannerSetTimerNew, '$tmpAddDate');<br />";

if (!mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO ADVERTISEMENTS(`user_id`, `ad_name`, `click_url`, `img_url`, `bg_color`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `timer_delay`, `add_date`) VALUES ($tmpUserID, '$advertisementNameNew', '$destinationURLNew', '$dropboxUploadFile', '$backgroundColorNew', '$bannerStartDateNew', '$bannerEndDateNew', $bannerSetTimerNew, '$tmpAddDate');")) {
    printf("Error Code: %s\n",  mysqli_errno($link));
    echo "<br />";
    printf("Error Msg: %s\n",  mysqli_error($link));
}
```

I know that the database connection is working. I am able to select and update tables. I can also insert into other tables with different queries.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please Echo all the Variables before insertion query, so that you can know whether the values are missing or not.

Comment: I think you're not using `mysqli` [the good way](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php); and I notice that you ended your statment with a `;`, which may not be necessary in API calls.

Comment: try `(accent)ADVERTISEMENTS(accent)` lose the ; at the end ... where you echo the line store it to a variable `echo $query = "INSERT INT....` then in your `if(!(mysqli_query($link,$query))){}`

Comment: Can you tell me what is returned by DateStringToMySQL function? Also, change the quotes used in the query and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passerby, thank you for your comment. This was my first experience with using mysqli, I changed my query to use the "bind_param" method, and everything works now. For anyone else with a similar problem, here is the corrected code...

```
        $mysqli = new mysqli($UM_Settings["database_options"]["server_name"], $UM_Settings["database_options"]["username"], $UM_Settings["database_options"]["password"], $UM_Settings["database_options"]["database_name"]);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $advertisementNameNew = $_POST['advertisementNameNew'];
    $destinationURLNew = $_POST['destinationURLNew'];
    $dropboxUploadFile = $_POST['dropboxUploadFile'];
    $backgroundColorNew = $_POST['backgroundColorNew'];
    $bannerStartDateNew = DateStringToMySQL($_POST['bannerStartDateNew']);
    $bannerEndDateNew = DateStringToMySQL($_POST['bannerEndDateNew']);
    $bannerSetTimerNew = intval($_POST['bannerSetTimerNew']);
    $tmpUserID = UM_GetCookie("UM_UserID");
    $tmpAddDate = DateStringToMySQL('now');

    /* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `ADVERTISEMENTS` (`user_id`, `ad_name`, `click_url`, `img_url`, `bg_color`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `timer_delay`, `add_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->bind_param("issssssis",$tmpUserID, $advertisementNameNew, $destinationURLNew, $dropboxUploadFile, $backgroundColorNew, $bannerStartDateNew, $bannerEndDateNew, $bannerSetTimerNew, $tmpAddDate)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }


    $_GET['ad_id'] = $stmt->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few errors in your query strings.

First, all your variables are passed as literal strings: "... VALUES ($tmpUserID, '$advertisementNameNew', ..." should be "... VALUES (".$tmpUserID.", '".$advertisementNameNew."', ...".

Second, I see missing quotes around $bannerSetTimerNew.

Third, there is an extra ;.

here's how I would write the query:

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO ADVERTISEMENTS (user_id, ad_name, click_url, img_url, bg_color, start_date, end_date, timer_delay, add_date) VALUES (".$tmpUserID.", '".$advertisementNameNew."', '".$destinationURLNew."', '".$dropboxUploadFile."', '".$backgroundColorNew."', '".$bannerStartDateNew."', '".$bannerEndDateNew."', '".$bannerSetTimerNew."', '".$tmpAddDate."')")) { ...
```

I didnt test it though.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see a `;` at the end of the query. Are you sure that should be there?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things
1. Remove the ; from at the end of the query.
2. I hope timer_delay field has datatype "Int" if its a VARCHAR then you will have to include quotes for that field value.

I hope this will help.